# Java Mongo Index query

Tags: java, mongodb

There is 1M data in Mongodb, data format like this:

```
key:"xyz", time:10
```

And I am writing a Java Program to query data from Mongodb based on both "key" and "time" range, like

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("key", "xyz")
          .append("time", new BasicDBObject("$gt", 99999).append("$lt", 100010));
```

Before querying, I set Index for "Key" and "time" fields first, like this:

```
table.ensureIndex(new BasicDBObject("key", 1));
table.ensureIndex(new BasicDBObject("time", 1));
```

And query performance actually works fine (about 4k per sec). So my question is that I set the index for "key" and "time" to 1 means ascending order in this case. What about I set them to -1 or one of them 1, the other is -1? What is the performance difference between 1 and -1 based on my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For single field indexes, it doesn't really matter if you specify ascending or descending order.  There wouldn't be any performance impact.

The order matters only for compound indexes (i.e, indexes created on 2 or more fields).  If we create a compound index on both "key" (asc) and "time" (desc) fields i.e., {key:1, time:-1}, then the query db.collection.find({key:"xyz", time:10}) will use the index only for the first part of the query, that is, just for filtering the documents using "key".  Second part of the index is not used.

Also, only index is used by MongoDB for a query.  In the case you have described, since you have created 2 separate indexes, only the "key" index is used.  If you create a compound index {key:1, time:1} (both ascending), then your query will perform better.

Comment: OK, so you mean if I set like "table.ensureIndex(new BasicDBObject("key",1).append("time", 1));" , the performance will better, right?

Comment: Correct.  That index will be used by MongoDB for both your query criteria i.e., key and time.

Comment: Perfect. I will test it.

Comment: I have another question. If I insert another 1M data into MongoDb after that, do I need to do "ensureIndex" again? Or just one time at the beginning and no matter we insert again and again

Comment: It is sufficient to create an index on a collection just once.  No need to do it again and again.  But please keep in mind, that there's cost involved when you insert new documents after an index is created, because the index will need to be updated in addition to inserting the document.

Comment: Good. That's what I want to know